# Number formatted as text while exporting kendo grid to excel

Tags: excel, kendo-ui, number-formatting

I am using Kendo Grid which i need to export to excel as well. For displaying in the grid I am setting the format: '{0:n2}' to display the numbers in proper format. However, when I export this the columns are exported as Numbers formatted as text. While exporting I want to keep my columns as number only and not text so i could perform sum and avg in the excel. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [excelExport](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-excelExport) event and set format in that.

Check [this dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/eJeyE) example to see ho to format cells as numbers.

Also check [this link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/data-management/grid/how-to/excel/column-template-export) to see how to keep templates.